# Asp.NET web api client side http status codes (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-web-api

I am developing an application using the Asp.net web API.
I can catch status codes with java script.

Just need to catch up to 200 status codes. What are your suggestions for other generic status codes?

Comment: It's hard to discern what your actual question is

Answer (score 0):

try to use some thing like below code

```
public HttpResponseMessage GetUser(HttpRequestMessage request)
{
    var users = new DataEntities().Users.List();
    return request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, user);
}
```